# Looping through a column searching, and copying each cell's row, as long as it meets certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I decided on trying to autofiter anything that does not meet my criteria and then selecting the remaining rows as a range. However, this code is buggy and has given me trouble. The column I am trying to loop through is Column "A", and then I copy the full range, and paste in another sheet in the workbook named Payroll Journal in a specific Range("B9:E28") The full code that I am using for this is:

---

```
Sub Filter_by_Tax()

    'Filter_by_Tax Macro
    Cells.Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("dat.").Range("A1:D100").AutoFilter Field:="1", _
            Criteria1:=">199999", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<200240"
End Sub

Sub Copy_and_Paste_Tax()
    'Copy  Tax into the Payroll Journal
    Dim rngT1 As Range

    'Set the worksheet name and range appropriately
    Set rngT1 = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    rngT1.Copy

    'Paste Tax in payroll Journal
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B9:E28").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Rows("1:1").Select

    'Turn off Filter
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

---

I would rather try looping than the autofilter, if anyone has any ideas...

Comment: On which line does the error happen.

Comment: Sorry forgot mention, I would prefer to loop through column A, and copy the rows that meet the criteria specified above, but have been having trouble understanding how to use a loop. If someone could help me out with that, thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your post with the rest of your code? What you have supplied here would not even compile.

Comment: Ok, I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and code are not clear:

> ...copy the full range, and paste in another sheet in the workbook
>   named Payroll Journal in a specific Range("B9:E28")...

- by *copy the full range* you are probably referring to the entire row

  - but if the row is "A2:F2" it will not fit on the other sheet on row "B9:E9"
- *...workbook named Payroll Journal* - your code refers to the **Sheet** Payroll Journal in the same file
- why do you prefer looping over the Autofilter - the loop is much slower

---

Bellow are 2 versions - first using the AutoFilter, the second using a loop

- both copy the entire rows that fit the criteria from "dat." to "Payroll Journal" starting at B9

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterByTaxAutoFilter()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDst As Worksheet

    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dat.")
    Set wsDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Payroll Journal")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wsSrc.UsedRange
        If wsSrc.AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:="1", Criteria1:=">199999", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<200240"
        If .Cells(1).Value2 > 199999 And .Cells(1).Value2 < 200240 Then
            .Copy wsDst.Range("B9")
        Else
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy wsDst.Range("B9")
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub FilterByTaxLoop()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDst As Worksheet, cel As Range, wsDstRow As Long

    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dat.")
    Set wsDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Payroll Journal")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wsDstRow = 9
    With wsSrc.UsedRange
        For Each cel In .Columns(1).Cells
            If cel.Value2 > 199999 And cel.Value2 < 200240 Then
                .Rows(cel.Row).Copy wsDst.Range("B" & wsDstRow)
                wsDstRow = wsDstRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

The loop version is just to demonstrate how you can iterate over all the cells with data (UsedRange) in column A, but this causes a lot of interaction with the Range object - reading and copying each cell and row, one at the time, is much slower than copying and pasting all rows in one operation, like using the AutoFilter

If you don't have the AutoFilter option, a better/faster way of looping over data is to copy the entire range to an array, again in one operation. The 2-dimensional array (in memory) is conceptually similar to the data on the sheet - dimension 1 is rows, dimension 2 - columns

Example:

- declare an array: `Dim arr As Variant`
- copy all data from the range: **`arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dat.").UsedRange`**
- update cell A2 on the range: `Cells(2, 1) = "Test Range"`
- update cell A2 in the array: `arr(2, 1) = "Test Array"`
- copy data from array back to the range: **`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dat.").UsedRange = arr`**

Comment: Awesome, the first one worked well. Thanks a bunch Paul!